# Clustering time series of measurements in R

Tags: r, clustering

I have a dataframe consisting time series of measurements taken every hour for 366 days or a year. Below is shown a sample of hourly measurements for the first two weeks. I want to cluster days with similar profile of hourly measurements. By using R, how can I group days with similar profiles? Thanks.

```
       Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7 Day8 Day9 Day10 Day11 Day12 Day13 Day14
Hour1    11   14   20   23   51   13   18   15    8    25    13    24     8    48
Hour2     2   13   21   19   21   17    8    6   11    21    16    25    11    18
Hour3     5    6    7   13   14    6    8    9    7    15    12    11     2    11
Hour4     6    4    6   18   11    2   10    4    5    20    10    10     3     8
Hour5     4   12    5   13    7   13    7    9   17    15    22     9     1     4
Hour6    33   33   25   20   13   46   29   42   27    22    32    29    30    10
Hour7    65   72   70   19   12   72   73   66   75    21    80    74    62     9
Hour8    79  105   78   45   30   87  107   75   86    47    91    82    76    27
Hour9    96   64   75   48   34   89   96   91   96    50   101    79    93    31
Hour10   73   91   70   80   42  103   63   82   79    82    84    74    70    39
Hour11   61   65   71   82   48   64   65   70   66    84    71    75    58    45
Hour12   54   59   99   71   62   68   85   65   58    73    63   103    51    59
Hour13   85   69  106   95   83   57   67   74   73    97    78   110    82    80
Hour14   78   75  108   72   82   58   80   78   70    74    75   112    75    79
Hour15   65   93   95   89   66   72   91   75   78    91    83    99    62    63
Hour16   95   98   92   88   94  103  108   88   88    90    93    96    92    91
Hour17   97  118   95   95   85  125  113  106  106    97   111    99    94    82
Hour18   86   86  114  106   83  104   98   84  109   108   114   118    83    80
Hour19  101   95  105   90   71   84   89   85  103    92   108   109    98    68
Hour20   60   55  102   56   55   46   72   61   71    58    76   106    57    52
Hour21   55   51   54   57   65   42   58   42   36    59    41    58    52    62
Hour22   45   34   23   30   33   51   45   56   37    32    42    27    42    30
Hour23   44   31   36   43   34   29   30   44    0    45     5    40    41    31
Hour24   25   17   30   40   14   24   17   15   28    42    33    34    22    11
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/time-series-clustering-in-r