# clustering analysis of large amount of time series

Tags: r, time-series, machine-learning, clustering, data-mining

I would like to cluster a set of time series, which are composed of around 50000 different time series. Are there established algorithms/package that can handle this scalability problem?

Comment: There are multiple questions similar to yours with multiple solutions in this forum  did you check those?

Comment: @forecast, I searched through the related post. I am still not very clear about the existing approaches for handling large scale time series. Thanks.

Comment: 50000 is not a large data set, the solutions proposed in this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/time-series-clustering-in-r?rq=1) could easily be used in millions if not billions of time series.