# Clustering of time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, classification, spss, data-mining

I have a set of almost 1600 time series on 2 years which I want to group into clusters. Do you think this is possible using k-means? Which method do you advice me to use? Is this possible at all using SPSS?

Comment: Related (but no SPSS solution): [Is it possible to do time-series clustering based on curve shape?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3331/930).

Comment: See [this article](http://e-learning.bahcesehir.edu.tr/coursecontent/CSE5155%20DATA%20MINING%20I/pdfs/Clustering%20of%20time%20series%20data%E2%80%94a%20survey.pdf) for situations when k-means is suitable and also other [similar questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/time-series-clustering).

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't use SPSS for that task. I have been using SPSS and Matlab for clustering (I'm a novice in clustering I have to say) but the difference in time and the flexibility is very noticeable between the 2 packages, being Matlab a better option even if it is also a high-level programming language. As far as I read R should be way faster, but I didn't try it yet. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

k-means cannot use arbitrary distance functions. It is designed for Euclidean distance.

Euclidean distance however does not work well for high-dimensional data such as your time series (unless you have a really low sampling rate, say 24 months)

For time series, you will probably want to use a *time series distance*. There are quire a lot designed specifically for different kinds of time series. You really should look at these.

They won't work with k-means, but there are various distance and density-based cluster algorithms (where usually density is defined by distance!) that you should try. However, I have no idea what SPSS supports. I don't know if it has any time series distances, either.

Comment: Thankyou for your help @Anony-Mouse. I have 130 weeks of sample actually.. I'm bit scared with the size of my data, but let's see if that works. I'll follow your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Well, 1 measurement per week, or 1 measurement per second, that is what I'm trying to point out...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes you can use k-means for cluster those time series. The default implementation of kmeans relies on the Euclidean distance, but can be modified to feed the algorithm with a specific time series distance, like DTW.

Check here for more information: [On Clustering Multimedia Time Series Data Using K-Means and Dynamic Time Warping](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4197360/).

Second, i don't think you can use SPSS for those purposes, but i do know that you can use Matlab, there are plenty of implementations of kmeans and DTW avialable.