# Clustering longitudinal (trajectory) data

Tags: r, clustering, panel-data

I am hoping to implement an unsupervised technique that identifies distinct clusters of individuals based on longitudinal data: 100 continuous or categorical variables measured at different ages.

A lot of the functionality provided by R packages seems to have been developed for simpler cases (eg with just one variable measured at different time points), so I was wondering what the best way to approach such a problem with R might be and which techniques (eg Latent Class Modelling) are considered to perform best.

Comment: I have used Latent Transition Analysis with discretized continuous variables and other categoricals. Not sure if R supports it, but you can do it in SAS. In terms of unsupervised...I assume you want to use this for data mining or something?

Comment: @toomuchpj The [poLCA](http://dlinzer.github.io/poLCA/) R package offers some facilities for Latent Class Analysis as well.

Comment: Yes, I do want to use it for data mining and identifying distinct subgroups (eg start with high values of x1, ..., x50 at early ages, then increases in x51, ..., x100 etc.) I will have a look at poLCA - any other tecniques that could be relevant?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13442/how-to-find-groupings-trajectories-among-longitudinal-data

Answer (score 1):

If you have a particular longitudinal variable you are interested in, you could take an unsupervised approach on the covariates using either a mixed-effects regression tree or latent growth curve structural equation modeling tree. For SEM trees, see this for more info: http://brandmaier.de/semtree/user-guide/