# Studying fluctuations / trajectories over time - objective methods of grouping?

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition, sequential-pattern-mining

I'm trying to study fluctuations of a disease's activity over time, for example the f;uctiation in severity of chronic pain (in the absence of obvious triggers).

Individuals generally demonstrate one of a number of trajectories; eg. those with constant severe pain, those with minimal pain, those with flares once/year, those with several flares, pattern-less individuals etc.

I've noticed several existing studies grouping them subjectively, by appearance (see figure).

[image]

Is there an objective / statistical approach to group and/or describe these patterns? (for a novice)

Thank you

Comment: So a statistician referred me to a text by Axen et al 2012 which recommended the following options 1) visual (as in above figure) with poor inter-observer reliability; 2) cluster analysis using hierarchical methods; 3) latent class analysis. And many others were mentioned that I don't recognize: artificial neural networks, probabilistic data mining. Anyone care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for an answer, there are several answers on CV that address similar questions:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2781/112640

[How to find groupings (trajectories) among longitudinal data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13442/how-to-find-groupings-trajectories-among-longitudinal-data)