# Correlation between several time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

So I have a set of around 50 time series for the same period of time, I want to determine how well correlated they are to each other (using R), I'm not an expert but what I have seen is that I should apply a cross correlation method.
Is this the best and most efficient way? and..

Should I use Pearson or Spearman rank correlation?
(the time series are meteorological data from different stations so they show usually normal distribution but in the case of precipitation it shows a seasonal pattern)

Please help me to determine the best method to find the similarity between the time series of one specific parameter.

Comment: Could be relevant (maybe a duplicate):  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66976/how-to-cluster-time-series